# Custom Checkbox for sitecore form not saving data in db

Tags: sitecore-forms, custom-field

I have Created a custom Checkbox field type  by duplicating the out of the box checkbox  field  type.

Only changed the View.

Ideally ,  my purpose is to get the display text (Model.Title in the code snippet )for the field from a rich text field which might contain a link.

I have not changed the model in my new custom field type.
When add the field in a form , display is correct but when checkbox is checked from a page it  is not saved in the DB.

Below is the View:

```
@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html
@model Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields.CheckBoxViewModel

@{
    string dbName = Sitecore.Context.Database.Name == "core" || Sitecore.Context.Database.Name == "master" ? "master": "web" ;
    Sitecore.Data.Database datbase = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(dbName);
    var consentItem = datbase.GetItem(new Sitecore.Data.ID(Constants.FormConsentTextItem));

    Model.Title = consentItem.Fields["ConsentText"].Value;

}
    <label class="@Model.LabelCssClass">
        <input type="checkbox" id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.CssClass" @if (Model.Value) { <text> checked="checked" </text> } value="true" data-sc-tracking="@Model.IsTrackingEnabled" data-sc-field-name="@Model.Name" data-sc-field-key="@Model.ConditionSettings.FieldKey" @Html.GenerateUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(m => Model.Value) />@Html.Raw(Model.Title)
        <input type="hidden" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" value="false" />
    </label>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Allow Save` option is checked by navigating in content editor to your custom field `/sitecore/Forms/Custom Form/Page/Section/Custom Field`. If you don't have the checkbox present then you need to inherit the `/sitecore/templates/System/Forms/Save Settings` template on your custom checkbox field template

[image]